# Can the confidence interval of an odds ratio be negative?

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio

I am running logistic regression.

The odds ratio estimate I got is positive but the lower bound of my 95% CI is negative (close to -1) and the upper bound is greater than 1. Would this mean that my result is not statistically significant?

In a hypothetical case that the odds ratio 95% CI is something like (-1, .5), would this also mean it is not statistically significant? The odds ratio in this hypothetical situation is not 0 or negative.

I used stargazer in R to get the 95% CIs, and these are the optional arguments I put in stargazer: `apply.coef = exp,ci = TRUE, ci.level = .95`

Comment: 1. The "baseline" for an insignificant odds ratio is 1 - when there's no difference in the probability of the two events - so yes, this means your result is not significant *at the 95% level of confidence*.  2. The odds ratio cannot be negative, but, if the CI is calculated using approximations to the true distribution, the *calculated* CI can contain negative numbers.

Comment: @jbowman one more question, first thanks for your response! according to the stargazer documentation the p-values calculated are with normal distribution since I specified ```apply.coef = exp```. My question is, regarding a negative value in the lower bound of the CIs, would the same interpretation hold true for binomial or poisson distributions?

Comment: Yes, doubly so with the binomial probability parameter as it's bounded both above and below.

Comment: @jbowman thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Odds ratios cannot be negative.

An odds ratio of 1.0 is the no-difference null hypothesis value. Values between 0 and 1 denote an effect in one direction. Values greater than 1 denote effects in the other direction.

Negative values are not possible, so the values you are looking at are not odds ratios. Maybe they are logarithms of odds ratios?

Comment: My odds ratio (the result itself) is not negative but the 95% CI contains a negative lower bound, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @ineedhelp. Your question was clear. But a properly constructed confidence interval only includes plausible values. Negative values are not plausible so something is wrong.

Comment: two more questions, first thanks for pointing that out.

1. regardless of the distribution type, negative 95% CIs for odds ratios cannot exist?

2. I checked with the MASS library in R (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/11/example-9-14-confidence-intervals-for-logistic-regression-models/) using its ```confint.default``` and got realistic 95% CIs, not sure if you use R but do you know why stargazer (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) would give those answers?

Comment: @ineedhelp. I know only a bit about R and never heard of StarGazer before. But I pulled up the link you referred to, and searched for "logistic". It doesn't appear in the document. So it appears that StarGazer does not do logistic regression.